# Inductor behaviour in LC oscillation

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, capacitance, inductance

I want to ask that in LC oscillation , when the capacitor is discharging then on other side the current is increasing in inductor do inductor should act means it should oppose the current ....as same when current is charging the capacitor by inductor then again it should oppose the current and it won't gain its maximum value due self inductance of inductor.

Comment: Welcome new user! I am having difficulty understanding what you are trying to ask here. But perhaps your misunderstanding stems from inductors resisting *changes* in current rather than resisting current itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inductance of the inductor, $L$, and the capacitance of the capacitor, $C$, control the rate at which energy oscillates between them.
The period of oscillation is $2\pi\sqrt LC$ which means that as the magnitude of the inductance gets larger then the period of oscillation gets larger which can be interpreted as a larger inductance resisting the change in the current more.
However even though the inductor opposes the current changing it can never stop the current changing.

The answer to this question [Why current flows in an inductor?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/505199/why-current-flows-in-an-inductor/505208#505208) tries to explain that although there is opposition to a current changing due to inductance in a circuit, the current still does change.
A larger inductance makes the change occur over a longer period of time.